# XSLT 2.0 Replace all occurrences of '&' (if any) from xml with 'and'

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I am very new to xslt and need some help with some string manipulation. I am trying to work on a xslt where i want to replace all occurrences of special character '&' with 'and' in xml. One of the few things i have tried

```
<xsl:template match="Model">
    <Model>
       <xsl:value-of select="replace(//P1/P2/Vehicles/Vehicle/Model, '&amp;','and')"/> 
    </Model>
</xsl:template>
```

it is working fine if there is only one vehicle, however if there are multiple vehicles it is not working.

The xml:

```
<P1>
  <someNode>
  <P2>
    <Vehicles>
        <Vehicle>
           <Id>1</Id>
           <Make>My car</Make>
           <Model>my model & something</Model>
        </Vehicle>
        <Vehicle>
            <Id>2</Id>
            <Make>My car2</Make>
            <Model>my model2</Model>
        </Vehicle>
    </Vehicles>
  </P2>
 <P1>
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provided XML is not well-formed. I had to fix it.

The XSLT is using Identity Transform pattern.

**XML**

```
<P1>
    <someNode/>
    <P2>
        <Vehicles>
            <Vehicle>
                <Id>1</Id>
                <Make>My car</Make>
                <Model>my model &amp; something</Model>
            </Vehicle>
            <Vehicle>
                <Id>2</Id>
                <Make>My car2</Make>
                <Model>dog &amp; pony</Model>
            </Vehicle>
        </Vehicles>
    </P2>
</P1>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Model">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '&amp;','and')"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks a lot that actually worked. i invested like 3 hours yesterday trying to figure out. really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace all occurrences of `&amp;`, another option is to use an [xsl:character-map](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-character-map)...

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" use-character-maps="cmap"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:character-map name="cmap">
        <xsl:output-character character="&amp;" string="and"/>
    </xsl:character-map>
    
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Working fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93wniTP